# Executing a plugin goal just once on a multi-module project

Tags: maven

I'm trying to start and stop a database using the `fabric8io/docker-maven-plugin` and I got this to work using the `pre-integration-test` and the `post-integration-test` phases.

The problem is that in a multi-module project, starting the database container takes 3-4 seconds and it's started and stopped for each module.

I've been trying to make this start/stop just once per Maven execution, no matter where I start this from (the main aggregation module or another lower aggregation sub-module or even for one of the actual modules), but I can't find a way.

The structure looks something like this:

- parent

  - sub-parent-a

    - sub-parent-b

      - module-a
      - module-b
      - module-c
  - sub-parent-c

I tried running something like `mvn clean docker:start@integration-db-start verify docker:stop@integration-db-stop`, but runs the goals for each module.

I've tried defining the plugin and its `execution` in the `parent/pom.xml` with `inherited=false`, but if I run `maven` in `sub-parent-a` or lower, the configuration isn't found, I assume because it's not *inherited* anymore.

In my searches, I found that a plugin could work in the way I want if it's marked as an `aggregator` plugin, like `javadoc`, but I don't think I can do anything for an existing plugin.

Is there any way that I've overlooked?

Thank you

Comment: I suggest taking a deep look into https://www.testcontainers.org/ that will make it simply possible to start a container within an unit/integration test...Using this setup will not really work...

Comment: I did try it, using their own JDBC driver and `tc` URL, but it takes longer to start a PostgreSQL Docker image than with `fabric8io/docker-maven-plugin` and the initial problem remains... it starts one instance per Maven module.

Comment: The PostgreSQL docker container takes 2-5 seconds to start. If you are writing this kind of integration tests that are the costs you have to pay. But you are sure you have only one and not changed something in your postgres by any other test in contradiction to the solution with starting it only once...

Comment: The current setup uses an actual PG instance that has to be installed locally by each developer and I was trying to change that, but it would be a harder sell for the team if I tell them the build will take 80 seconds more (20 modules x 4 seconds).
I was thinking that I could create my own Mojo that would extend the `StartMojo` from `docker-maven-plugin` and just mark it with `aggregator=true`

Comment: You could not because the mojo is bound to the lifecycle which will not help here... apart from that such integration test should run only on CI and not locally only exceptionally if there is a bug to be hunted...

Comment: I've done a comparison run between the PG started with the `docker-maven-plugin` and a local PG instance and it's huge: `30:51` minutes vs `18:37` minutes, the difference is huge. Even with just 3-4 seconds per module to start the db, the tests run much slower, no idea why.